# Simulating inheritance+mutable state with immutable objects

Tags: scala, immutability

I'm having a problem modelling our domain with immutable objects.

**Mutable design**

One base trait WObject (world object) and loads of traits for implementing specific operations like OwnedObj (hp/owner/takeDamage), Movable (movementLeft/moveTo), Fighter (attacked/attack).

At the end of the hierarchy you have a mutable class which mixes in the appropriate traits:

```
class Corvette(var position: Vect2) extends WObject with OwnedObj with Movable with Fighter
```

If a user wants to do an operation (lets say move a ship), you do:

```
val opt = objects.collectFirst { case obj: Movable if obj.position == position => obj }
opt.fold(Log.error(s"Movable at $position not found!")) { obj =>
  obj.moveTo(position) // return type is Unit
}
```

**Immutable design**

If *moveTo* has to return a new object, what type does it return?

I've tried using `trait Movable[Self <: Movable[Self]]` approach, but this requires to take Movable[_] everywhere and those existential types get out of hand quickly. What if I want `Movable[_] with Fighter[_]`? Are _ the same type?

I've also tried abstract type Self inside the traits with type bounds approach, but this starts to get hairy in following scenarios:

```
def takeDamage(obj: OwnedObj): obj.Self = if (Random.nextDouble()) obj.takeDamage else obj.self
```

Nest this a bit and you get types like

```
  def attackReachable(
    data: WObject.WorldObjUpdate[Self]
  ): WObject.WorldObjUpdate[data.value._2.Self]
```

Which are just horrible.

I was thinking about ditching inheritance and using composition + typeclasses, but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

For example:

```
case class WObject(position: Vect2, id: UUID=UUID.randomUUID())
case class OwnedObj(owner: Owner)
case class Movable(movementLeft: Int)
case class Fighter(attacked: Boolean)
case class Corvette(obj: WObject, owned: OwnedObj, movable: Movable, fighter: Fighter)

// Something that has both WObject and Movable
trait MovableOps[A <: ???] {
  def moveTo(obj: A, target: Vect2): A
}
```

And then define operations in typeclasses, which would be implemented in Corvette companion object.

But I am not sure how to specify the restrains.

More over how do you implement the move operation from client side?

```
val opt = objects.collectFirst { case obj: ??? if obj.position == position => obj }
opt.fold(Log.error(s"Movable at $position not found!")) { obj =>
  objects = objects - obj + obj.moveTo(position)
}
```

Help appreciated :)

Related: [Polymorphic updates in an immutable class hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801818/polymorphic-updates-in-an-immutable-class-hierarchy?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

You can write your "same _ in with" case using an existential: `(Movable[T] with Fighter[T] forSome {type T})`.

If I've understood your `attackReachable` example correctly, I wouldn't worry about the path-dependent types too much. You can usually allow them to be inferred, and the concrete calls will have "actual" types. Strategic use of implicit `=:=` or `Leibniz` parameters where you know the types are actually the same can stop things getting out of hand. Or more simply, you can just require that the type be the same:

```
def doSomething[T <: Moveable { type Self = T }](t: T): T =
  t.somethingThatReturnsTDotSelf()
```

If you want to go the composition route, the nicest approach I can think of is using shapeless Lenses (I can't compare with monocle Lenses as I haven't used them):

```
trait Move[A] {
  val lens: Lens[A, (WObject, Movable)]
}
/** This could be implicitly derived with Generic if you really want to -
or you could use Records. */
implicit def moveCorvette = new Move[Corvette] {
  val lens = lens[Corvette].obj ~ lens[Corvette].movable
}

def moveTo[A: Move](obj: A, target: Vect2) = {
  val l = Lens[A, (Wobject, Movable)]
  val remainingMoves = l.get(obj)._2.movementLeft - 1
  l.set(obj)((target, remainingMoves))
}
```

To apply this to a list, you either keep the list as a HList so that you know the types of all the elements (e.g. your list is of type `Fighter :: Corvette :: HNil`), or include the evidence in the list entries with an existential (e.g. `trait ObjAndMove {type T; val obj: T; val evidence: Move[T]}` and then use a `List[ObjAndMove]`)

Comment: attackReachable can do 2 things: 1) if the target cannot be attacked it should just return `data`. 2) if target can be reached, it should return updated data, where target will be changed and Self will be changed as well marking it as attacked. Because of the self type 1 becomes impossible because compiler has no idea that Self == data.value._2.Self (which is returned from the modification of Self)

Comment: Also can you elaborate on Monocle vs Shapeless lenses?

Comment: Also how do you call moveTo if you only have a list of different types (with lets say a base type of WorldObject)? Do you have to pattern match up to a concrete type for the typeclass to kick in?